# How to determine which vectors for a linear system gives a non trivial solution

Tags: matrices

I'm given this matrix A:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & -2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm asked for what vectors b does this linear system of equations Ax=b has a nontrivial solution. I know that I should take the transpose matrix of A and find the nullspace. I'm kind of lost on how to actually find the vectors b. Also sorry in advanced for any formatting errors. I'm not quite sure how to do an actual matrix.

Comment: I assume these are the column vectors of the matrix,yes?

Comment: @mbar Please check the matrix to see if it is correct.  You can check how I formatted the matrix by right-clicking on the matrix, then selecting Show Math As followed by Tex Commands.  You can find instructions on how to format mathematics on this site at this page: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

If you think of $b$ as a column vector, $b$ is in the span of the column vectors of $A$.

Can you find the rank of $A$ then find column vectors in $A$ that form a basis of the span of $A$? (That is very easy to do.) The vectors $b$ are then just the linear combinations of the basis of $A$. Any basis will do.

Here are some details: If the matrix as formatted by N.F. Taussig is correct, you can easily see that the first and third column vectors are equal. It is also clear that for the first two column vectors, neither is a multiple of the other. Therefore the first two column vectors are a basis of the span of $A$. The vectors $b$ that can be expressed as $Ax$ are then

$$b=r\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
  + s\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2\\ \end{bmatrix}
 =\begin{bmatrix} 2r+s \\ s \\ r-2s \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

There are also other ways to express the answer. Another way is to take the cross product of those basis vectors to get an equation that any vector $b$ must satisfy. The cross product of the vectors I used above is

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 5 \\ 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So we can say that if we let

$$b=\begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \\ e \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

then the possible vectors $b$ are those for which

$$-c+5d+2e=0$$

Comment: Bingo. Nice concise answer. An example computation would have made it even better,though.I get the impression the OP is a rank beginner and an example would probably help clarify your response immensely.

Comment: I'm letting him do some of the work. Also, I don't know which tools he understands: determinant, reduced row echelon form, etc.

Comment: Ok,got it. I could post a link to an explicit example for him,but out of respect for what you're trying to do here,I won't. You're on your own,kid. Tough love. : )

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: I added more detail, based on your encouragement. It's always hard to know just how much to give.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for the help! I'm not familiar with many of these operations, but I will try and make sense of it. Again, thanks!